# How to send data from Arduino MKR Wifi 1010 to AWS (or any other cloud service)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, arduino

I'm pretty new to all the Arduino stuff, forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I got the MKR Wifi 1010 connected to AWS via the ATECC508A chip onboard the Arduino.  I can securely send messages and instructions on the AWS console to the Arduino.

How do I send data back from the Arduino to AWS?  There is absolutely no documentation on this.  I'm making a weather station, so having data travelling both ways is pretty essential.  If there's no easy way to do this, I might even switch to Raspberry Pi, which from what I've seen is a lot simpler for data transfer to cloud services.

Comment: usually HttpClient or WiFiClient is used to send or request data to/from HTTP server

Answer (score -1):

This tutorial explain in detail how to communicate with AWS IoT Core: https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/mkr-wifi-1010/securely-connecting-an-arduino-mkr-wifi-1010-to-aws-iot-core/